# add static time in calendars without timezone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, outlook, calendar

is there any chance to add a event in major calendars without checking timezone of calendar settings?

Like if event is from another country which is in different timezone at 10:00:00 than it should be add in my calendar at 10:00:00

Like this:

https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&subject=Afspraak%20uitnodiging&startdt=2019-06-29T10:00:00.000+0530&enddt=2019-06-29T10:30:00.000+0530&body=Bijgevoegd%20vind%20u%20de%20online%20uitnodiging%20voor%20uw%20afspraak.&location=Straatnaam%202B,%20A12BC3,%20Stad&allday=false&addcalendarlink=true

This event created from Netherlands which has timezone (+02:00) but right now i am in india timezone is (+05:30) but it is adding in my calendar in different time.

So i want to add a static time. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Outlook always uses UTC.
Tasks are the only exception, but they are timeless.

Comment: any solution about it?

Comment: As I mentioned above, no.

Answer (score 0):

You should always

- store utc time
- represent local time

For example, .. now is 12:45 circa. But I am living in Italy (UTC+1) and with Legal time, .. this means that in Italy the time is 14:45. In Tokyo (UTC+9) 20:45 and so on.

Comment: yes that i understand. but no matter what i am in timezone. if in URL parameter 10:00:00 mentioned than it should be add on 10:00:00 not related to timezone